# Fastlane match provisioning profile set device

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-match

Does anybody know if it is possible to set which devices should be added to provisioning profile, using fastlane match?

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to select which devices a provisioning profile will take on - `match` will use all devices as of right now.

Side note: There have been some requests to implement a solution for this so this may change in the future.